# How to disable the options lists until another dropdown is selected in reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown, angular-reactive-forms

I have ractive forms angular In that I need to disable the second dropdown until first down value is selected.

**.component.ts**

```
 public addNew() {
   
    this.infoForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      category:["", Validators.required],
      action: ["", Validators.required],
     
    });
   }
```

**.component.html**

```
//first dropdown
<select id="category" class="form-control" formControlName="category" required (change) ="changeList($event.target.value)" >
           <option>option1</option>
             <option>option2</option>
            <option>option3</option>  
          </select>

//second dropdown
           <select id="action" class="form-control" formControlName="action" required>
           <option>select1</option>
             <option>select2</option>
            <option>select3</option>  
          </select>
```

In the above I need to disable the dropdown until first down is selected.
I have tried with disabled attribute but not working
Can anyone helpme on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 <form [formGroup]="infoForm">
   //first dropdown
   <select id="category" class="form-control" formControlName="category" required>
     <option></option>
     <option value="1">option1</option>
     <option value="2">option2</option>
     <option value="3">option3</option>
   </select>
 
   //second dropdown
   <select id="action" class="form-control" formControlName="action" required [attr.disabled]="(category.value) ? null : true">
     <option value="1">select1</option>
     <option value="2">select2</option>
     <option value="3">select3</option>
   </select>
 
 </form>
```

I add more get function to do a short hand in `.ts` file

```
get category(): FormControl {
  return this.infoForm.get('category');
}
```

Comment: Thanks@paranaaan , Can we do this without adding the .ts and by using my ts file as in aboove code if yes can you helpmeon this  and I have edited my code in html file

Comment: of couse, change to `[attr.disabled]="(infoForm.get('category').value) ? null : true"` everything will still work.